# How to define escape character in perl

Tags: perl

I want to   define a variable  /Test123 in perl .I am trying something like this but i am getting error

```
    my $uriReference="Test123";

    ##Here is where i am  trying to create /Test123

    my $routingUrl = "\"/".$uriReference."\"";
```

I think i am doing some mistake here Need help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `qq()` instead to emulate double quote interpolation:

```
my $url = qq("/$uriReference");
```

Although I do not see anything technically wrong with your assignment, it should assign `"/Test123"` to your variable. So perhaps the error is about something else. We would know if you had included your error message in your question. There is no reason you should ever not include error messages in questions.

You should also know that you do not need to break up your quotes, you can do this:

```
my $url = "\"/$uriReference\"";
```